# gnuplot unable to read .dat file

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012, gnuplot

I have been stuck with this error  'gnuplot:unable to read data.dat'  error from 2 days.

I have put the file path also, but still the error is coming.I searched the internet and I am not getting it.

Thank you

```
void plotgraph(float *xvals, float *yvals, float *x1vals, int NUM_POINTS)
{

 int NUM_COMMANDS = 4;
//char * commandsForGnuplot[] = { "set title \"Concatenated Coding+OFDM[QPSK]\"", "set ylabel 'BER'", "set xlabel 'SNR'", "plot '\C:\\Users\\shreyasn\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Project1\\Project1\\data.temp\' with lines" };
//FILE * temp = fopen_s(&temp, "%temp%\\data.temp", "w");
//char *commandsForGnuplot[] = { "set title \"Concatenated Coding+OFDM[QPSK]\"", "set ylabel 'BER'", "set xlabel 'SNR'", "set logscale y", "set nologscale x", "plot 'data.temp' with lines title 'After coding' , \ 'data.temp1' with lines title 'Before coding'" };
// double xvals[NUM_POINTS] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
//double yvals[NUM_POINTS] = {5.0 ,3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0};
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
{
    printf("time: %f decod: %f encod: %f \n", xvals[i], x1vals[i], yvals[i]); //Write the data to a temporary file
}

errno_t err;
FILE *pipe;
FILE *temp9;
if ((err = fopen_s(&temp9, "data.dat", "w+")) != 0)
    printf("File not opened\n");
if (temp9 == NULL) { 
    printf("Error\n");
}

char * commandsForGnuplot[] = { "set title \"Concatenated Coding+OFDM[QPSK]\"", "set ylabel 'BER'", "set xlabel 'SNR'","plot '\C:\\Users\\shreyasn\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Project1\\Project1\\data.dat\' using 1:2 with lines" };
//char * commandsForGnuplot[] = { "set title \"Concatenated Coding+OFDM[QPSK]\"", "set ylabel 'BER'", "set xlabel 'SNR'", "plot 'data.dat' with lines" };
//FILE * temp1 = fopen_s(&temp1,"data.temp1", "w");
//char *path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin";
pipe = _popen("\"C:\\gnuplot\\binary\\gnuplot.exe\" -persistent", "w");
//Opens an interface that one can use to send commands as if they were typing into the
//    gnuplot command line.  "The -persistent" keeps the plot open even after your
//    C program terminates.
//




for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
{
    fprintf(temp9, "%f %f \n", xvals[i], yvals[i]); //Write the data to a temporary file
    //fprintf(temp1, "%lf %lf \n", xvals[i], x1vals[i]); //Write the data to a temporary file
}

fclose(temp9);
fflush(temp9);

for (i = 0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++)
{
    fprintf(pipe, "%s \n", commandsForGnuplot[i]); //Send commands to gnuplot one by one.
}
fflush(pipe);

}
```

Comment: 'pipe' is a system call in C, use a different name

Comment: if the file did not open, then I suspect that the program should exit, not continue with the next statements

Comment: cannot flush a file after it is closed. (and closing performs a flush anyway)

Comment: this line segment: 'char * commandsForGnuplot[]' should probably be: 'char ** commandsForGnuplot[][]' and the actual commands be formatted accordingly.  I.E. { {"command1"},{"command2"}, ... };

Comment: You have a wrong backslash as first character in the file name, and you don't need to escape single quotes. It should be `"plot 'C:\\Users...'"`.

Comment: @Christoph  I did as you told still same error is appearing

Comment: @Christoph I first created that data.dat file first. Then I copied that file to where gnuplot.exe was present, then I was able to see the graph. Could you please suggest how to overcome this?

Comment: From which path did you copy the file? You write the file using a relative path and the resulting absolute path doesn't match the absolute oath you are giving to gnuplot. Either use the very same absolute path for saving and plotting, or figure out where your output file ends up. In any case it is quite cumbersome to guess what you are doing every time!

Comment: @Christoph can you please tell me how to write the file using relative path?

Answer (score 0):

```
the following information, copied from elsewhere, 
it shows how to open a pipe.

prototype:
int pipe(intfd[2]);                                             
RETURNS: 0 success                                                       
         -1 on error: and set errno
```

NOTES: fd[0] is set up for reading, fd[1] is set up for writing

The first integer in the array (element 0) is set up and opened for reading, while the second integer (element 1) is set up and opened for writing. Visually speaking, the output of fd1 becomes the input for fd0. Once again, all data traveling through the pipe moves through the kernel.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    main()
    {
            int     fd[2];

            pipe(fd);
            .
            .
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the documentation on fopen_s states this about the mode string:
   (there are other allowed mode strings, but the following seems to
    be most useful)

"r+"
    Opens for both reading and writing. (The file must exist.)

"w+"
    Opens an empty file for both reading and writing. 
    If the file exists, its contents are destroyed.

```
So I suggest using the "r+" mode string rather than the "w+" mode string

the failure to open suggests that the user does not have
permission to overwrite the file.
```

Comment: Then how to get permission